# Give values to grid randomly and refer back to it

Tags: python-3.x

i was making this code and got stuck as i have to assign values to the `grid` randomly and refer back to it so in this case i have to assign `10` cells/section of grid to a treasure chest so if the user enters the grid reference of that grid which has a treasure chest, ten gold coins will be added into the total collection of of the player so this is my `code` so far......

```
import random

def menu():
    play=int(input('To play the game, press 1 and to exit, press 2'))
    if play==1:
        size=int(input('to play with 8x8 grid(This is the origional game), press 8, to play with 10x10 grid, press 10 and to play with 12x12 grid, press 12 '))
        if size==8:
            Grid=[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
            input('press enter when you would like to play')
        def printgrid():
            print('     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     ')
            print("  "+Grid[1]+"  |  "+Grid[2]+"  |  "+Grid[3]+"  |  "+Grid[4]+"  |  "+Grid[5]+"  |  "+Grid[6]+"  |  "+Grid[7]+"  |  "+Grid[8]+"   ")
            print("     |     |     |     |     |     |     |")        
            print("-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----")
            print('     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     ')
            print("  "+Grid[9]+"  |  "+Grid[10]+"  |  "+Grid[11]+"  |  "+Grid[12]+"  |  "+Grid[13]+"  |  "+Grid[14]+"  |  "+Grid[15]+"  |  "+Grid[16]+"   ")
            print("     |     |     |     |     |     |     |")        
            print("-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----")
            print('     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     ')
            print("  "+Grid[17]+"  |  "+Grid[18]+"  |  "+Grid[19]+"  |  "+Grid[20]+"  |  "+Grid[21]+" |  "+Grid[22]+"  |  "+Grid[23]+"  |  "+Grid[24]+"   ")
            print("     |     |     |     |     |     |     |")        
            print("-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----")
            print('     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     ')
            print("  "+Grid[25]+"  |  "+Grid[26]+"  |  "+Grid[27]+"  |  "+Grid[28]+"  |  "+Grid[29]+"  |  "+Grid[30]+" |  "+Grid[31]+"  |  "+Grid[32]+"   ")
            print("     |     |     |     |     |     |     |")        
            print("-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----")
            print('     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     ')
            print("  "+Grid[33]+"  |  "+Grid[34]+"  |  "+Grid[35]+"  |  "+Grid[36]+"  |  "+Grid[37]+"  |  "+Grid[38]+"  |  "+Grid[39]+"  |  "+Grid[40]+"   ")
            print("     |     |     |     |     |     |     |")        
            print("-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----")
            print('     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     ')
            print("  "+Grid[41]+"  |  "+Grid[42]+"  |  "+Grid[43]+"  |  "+Grid[44]+"  |  "+Grid[45]+"  |  "+Grid[46]+"  |  "+Grid[47]+"  |  "+Grid[48]+"   ")
            print("     |     |     |     |     |     |     |")        
            print("-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----")
            print('     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     ')
            print("  "+Grid[49]+"  |  "+Grid[50]+"  |  "+Grid[51]+"  |  "+Grid[52]+"  |  "+Grid[53]+"  |  "+Grid[54]+"  |  "+Grid[56]+"  |  "+Grid[57]+"   ")
            print("     |     |     |     |     |     |     |")        
            print("-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----")
            print('     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     ')
            print("  "+Grid[57]+"  |  "+Grid[58]+"  |  "+Grid[59]+"  |  "+Grid[60]+"  |  "+Grid[61]+"  |  "+Grid[62]+"  |  "+Grid[63]+"  |  "+Grid[64]+"   ")
            print("     |     |     |     |     |     |     |")        
            print("-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----")
        start=False
        while not False:

            printgrid()
            for x in range(10):
                Grid=random.randint.insert('x')
            place=int(input('Grid refrene'))
            if place==Grid==x:
                print('Done')

    elif play==2:
        print('Good bye')

menu()
```

Comment: okay, so what's the problem?

Comment: so basically i need to assign 10 random grids as treasure chest

Comment: `10_random_grids = 'treasure chest'`. That's not *really* your problem, is it?